# How to crash this C program?

Tags: c

Alright, so in a twist a bit different, I need help actually crashing this program. Don't worry, it's an assignment from my professor, though I'm not sure if this is the place to ask this question. He gave us this code to work with and the instruction to both crash it, and cause `secret[0]` and `secret[1]` to become modified by giving input for the two `scanf` functions. I've tried crashing it with different inputs but nothing yet.

(If this is the type of thing not wanted on this site, just let me know and I'll delete this question. Thanks for your time in advance!)

```
/* vul_prog.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SECRET1 0x44
#define SECRET2 0x55

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char user_input[100];
int *secret;
int int_input;
int a, b, c, d; /* other variables, not used here.*/

/* The secret value is stored on the heap */
secret = (int *) malloc(2*sizeof(int));

/* getting the secret */
secret[0] = SECRET1; secret[1] = SECRET2;

printf("The variable secret's address is 0x%8x (on stack)\n", (unsigned int)&secret);
printf("The variable secret's value is 0x%8x (on heap)\n", (unsigned int)secret);
printf("secret[0]'s address is 0x%8x (on heap)\n", (unsigned int)&secret[0]);
printf("secret[1]'s address is 0x%8x (on heap)\n", (unsigned int)&secret[1]);

printf("Please enter a decimal integer\n");
scanf("%d", &int_input);  /* getting an input from user */
printf("Please enter a string\n");
scanf("%s", user_input); /* getting a string from user */

/* Vulnerable place */
printf(user_input);
printf("\n");

/* Verify whether your attack is successful */
printf("The original secrets: 0x%x -- 0x%x\n", SECRET1, SECRET2);
printf("The new secrets:      0x%x -- 0x%x\n", secret[0], secret[1]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What kind of help do you need. He even marked the place you need to look at: /* Vulnerable place */

Comment: `printf` uses special character sequences to indicate where values taken from additional arguments should be printed.  Input a string like "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d" and you will trash the stack because you are not providing the additional arguments

Comment: Using user input as a format string -- what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: You should run this under debugger, examine the relative memory locations of the variables you need to maliciously modify, then figure out how to achieve that with the code marked as the vulnerable spot.

Comment: Although overflowing `user_input` by entering an extremely large string may work, the `/* Vulnerable place */` comment suggests it's supposed to crash in `printf()` because of the *contents* of the string, not in `scanf()` because of the length...

Comment: See that's what I've been trying. I've tried an incredibly long %d string, still didn't crash it. I've tried a few different tricks to try and get it to crash but the program itself still completes and doesn't crash. Nor does secret[0] or secret[1] get modified. =\

Comment: Actually a string of "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s" would have a better chance at being interpreted as a bunch of wild pointers, one which may point to invalid memory

Comment: Nice one. That actually caused a crash right away. Now I just gotta figure out how to modify the secret value. Obviously you can pop it off the stack using something like "%x" but I don't know how to modify it based on user input from there.

Comment: entering too long a string will overwrite the pointer in `secret`, making it point elsewhere.  That would make if say something different.   Picking characters to point back into the stack, and adding those characters to the input string would do it.  But you need to find where the stack is getting placed.  A bunch of `%x` in the format may be able to disclose that.  Then craft a new string using that information

Comment: Yeah tried using a bunch of %x in the format, but I don't see it printing back the 60fea8 address (this is apparently its address according to the first printf of the program).

Comment: A lot will depend on the CPU type,and size of `int` and endian-ess and how the compiler handles parameters in calls.  Using a `%lx` or maybe even `%llx` may give you more bytes in a row.  But then you might have to re-order them to interpret them

Comment: Well I'm still kind of lost then lol.

Comment: Try making a format string with a dozen `%lx` at the start,  then pad it up to 100 characters with capital U's.  Those should print out as "55" in the hex output.  That will give you a handle on where the offset to the end of `user_input` buffer is

Comment: Ok so let me see if I got this right: "%1x%1x%1x%1x%1x%1x%1x%1x%1x%1x%1x%1x%UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU" is what you're telling me to give as input? Is this for the first or second input? Because I do it for both and they still just show up as "U"s in the output.

Comment: That's a lowercase L for long, not a one.  You should see the actual U's, but hopefully in the hex part you'll see 55's too.  Also ntering 305419896 at the first `scanf` will read as "12345678" hex inside `int_input`, which would not only be a marker, but give you a clue to endian-ess

Comment: Alright, so the input at the first one (int_input) will be: "305419896" (i've been using 65535 to give back 'ffff' so far). After that, it's a string of "%lx%lx%lx%lx%lx%lx%lx%lx%lx%lx" followed by "UUUUUUUUUU" is what you're suggesting right? And I'm looking for where the "305419896" shows up as "12345678" right? And then what?

Comment: You can see how much longer than 100 your format string has to be to reach `int_input`.  If you clobber those, the pointer in `secret` will be clobbered, and the 'new secret' printf should be something different.  Although it might crash if `secret` points to invalid memory.  Then you'll have to play with the format to find a non-crashing ones

Comment: Well if you're talking about when "12345678" shows up in the output, it comes from about 5 "%lx" from the start. I figured that using a "%n" after it would change the pointer but it's not so I'm still at a lost for what to do here? What do you mean by 'clobbered' exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125543/discussion-between-infixed-and-gllwrnce).

Comment: Take a look at what the `%n` format specifier to printf does....